# Pruning eggplant for optimal fruit

Tags: pruning, eggplant

I have a solitary eggplant that has several fruit growing (picture below).  It's not terribly tall, in part because of the more successful squash nearby, but my soil is very good quality (amended with 3" of mushroom compost this year).

How many eggplants should I let it grow at once?  Should I let all of them develop, or cut most of them off?  Is the plant even big enough to allow it to make any fruit?

[image: eggplant picture]
[image: garden picture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its extremely difficult to tell much from your pictures - it would be good if they showed the height - but from what little I can see, there are way too many flowers on the tree (although it looks quite healthy).

Commercially we would let to stems grow, with 2 fruit per stem at a time.

I believe you will get a better yield if you greatly reduce the number of flowers - at minimum get rid of all except for 1 flower for each clump (it looks to me like you have clumps of flowers).

If your plant is only 50cm or so in height, I'd be surprised if you wanted it to have more then 3 fruit growing at once.   (more fruit puts more stress on the plant, as well as slower growth/yield)

Comment: The plant is around 20cm (9 in) high actually - not nearly 50cm.

Comment: What kind of eggplant then ?  I suspect its not the larger "Black Beauty" European style one ?  Ours would have come from the nursery at almost that height - and still had a months growing before they started yielding their first fruit.  I suspect I may not actually have enough knowledge to answer your question as your variety must be different !

Comment: Unfortunately I don't recall. I think it may be a Japanese style eggplant but I managed to get one that didn't have a marker. It was about ten cm tall when I got it from the nursery; I'm sure some of the problem is the squash which I have to keep pruning back.